# how to use DefaultTimeBar outSide of PlayerView in Android

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I am using playerview and i want to display progress of the video. So i used PlayerView and used LinearLayout below the playerview, and inside LinearLayout i have used PlayerView ***<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar>*** But i don't know how to connect it with Playerview. i don't want any controls on the Playerview , it should be outside of playerview.

My Code is given belew:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:visibility="visible">

</com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView>

     <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar
       android:id="@+id/exo_progress1"
       style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my requirement

[image: Requirement]

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PlayerActivity">

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/player"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        app:use_controller="false" // disabling default controlls, or you can just use SurfaceView instead
        android:background="@color/purple_700"
        app:controller_layout_id="@layout/custom_controlls"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar
        android:id="@+id/tim_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:scrubber_color="@color/purple_500"
        app:played_color="@color/black"
        app:unplayed_color="@color/gray"
        app:buffered_color="@color/purple_700"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Kotlin class file

```
class PlayerActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player)

        val player: ExoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build()
        val timeBar = findViewById<DefaultTimeBar>(R.id.exo_progress1)
        val playerView = findViewById<PlayerView>(R.id.videoView)
        playerView.player = player

        val firstItem: MediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(
            Uri.parse("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/SubaruOutbackOnStreetAndDirt.mp4")
        )
        val secondItem: MediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(
            Uri.parse("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/VolkswagenGTIReview.mp4")
        )
        player.addMediaItem(firstItem)
        player.addMediaItem(secondItem)
        player.prepare()
        player.play()

        player.addListener(object : Listener {
            override fun onPlaybackStateChanged(playbackState: Int) {
                super.onPlaybackStateChanged(playbackState)
                // Once the player is ready you can get the track duration
                if (playbackState == Player.STATE_READY) {
                    timeBar.setDuration(player.duration) // set duration to timeBar
                    lifecycleScope.launch { // here is some example of how you can get the current position from player and set to the timeBar and Yes you have to manage that on your own now as you do not want to use default controls 
                        while (player.isPlaying) {
                            delay(1000L) // update per second
                            timeBar.setPosition(player.currentPosition)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have a workaround for this case. The idea is you still put the DefaultTimeBar inside PlayerView controller layout and then you move the DefaultTimeBar view manually to outside the PlayerView, which is in LinearLayout for your case.

*R.layout.main*

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mainView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:controller_layout_id="@layout/exo_playback_control_view" />

</LinearLayout>
```

*R.layout.exo_playback_control_view*

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar
       android:id="@+id/exo_progress"
       style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then, somewhere in your activity/fragment, move manually the view (I'm using Kotlin for example here).

```
val mainView = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.mainView)
val videoView = findViewById<PlayerView>(R.id.videoView)
val defaultTimeBarView = videoView.findViewById<DefaultTimeBar>(R.id.exo_progress)

val parent = defaultTimeBarView.parent as? ViewGroup
parent?.removeView(defaultTimeBarView)
mainView.addView(defaultTimeBarView)
```

But, there is still weird animation on the progressbar if the PlayerView's controller view visibility is hidden, but if it's visible then progressbar works.